Best way to reduce requests using Zustand?
Im building an APP, basically a large scale CRUD, and want to make it the more scalable possible...
I was initially making a fetch every for every list in the app, when I thought about making global zustand states, and fetch all the data one time in the app.jsx, and instead of making fetch in every list, just use the state that is storing the list of objects I need.
Is this ok? Is there a better way to reduce Requests?
Just in case here is the global store I created.
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { getPatients } from '../hooks/patients/getPatients'
import { getServices } from '../hooks/services/getServices'
import { getProducts } from '../hooks/products/getProducts'
import { getRecords } from '../hooks/records/getRecords' // Assuming you have a getRecords function
import { getProductCategories } from 'src/hooks/products/categories/getProductCategories'
import { getProductProviders } from 'src/hooks/products/providers/getProductProviders'
import { getServiceCategories } from 'src/hooks/services/categories/getServiceCategories'
import { getServiceVariations } from 'src/hooks/services/variations/getServiceVariations'

export const useGlobalStore = create(set => ({
  patients: [],
  services: [],
  serviceCategories: [],
  serviceVariations: [],
  products: [],
  productCategories: [],
  productProviders: [],
  records: [],
  orders: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
  setRecords: records => set({ records }),
  
  setProducts: products => set({ products }),
  setPatients: patients => set({ patients }),
  setServices: services => set({ services }),
  setServiceVariations: serviceVariations => set({ serviceVariations }),
  setProductCategories: productCategories => set({ productCategories }),
  setProductProviders: productProviders => set({ productProviders }),
  setServiceCategories: serviceCategories => set({ serviceCategories }),
  fetchPatients: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const patients = await getPatients()
      set({ patients })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },

  fetchServices: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const services = await getServices()
      set({ services })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },

  fetchProducts: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const products = await getProducts()
      set({ products })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },

  fetchRecords: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const records = await getRecords()
      set({ records })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },
  fetchProdCategories: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const productCategories = await getProductCategories()
      set({ productCategories })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },
  fetchProdProviders: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const productProviders = await getProductProviders()
      set({ productProviders })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },
  fetchServCategories: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const serviceCategories = await getServiceCategories()
      set({ serviceCategories })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  },
  fetchServVariations: async () => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null })
    try {
      const serviceVariations = await getServiceVariations()
      set({ serviceVariations })
    } catch (error) {
      set({ error: error.message })
    } finally {
      set({ isLoading: false })
    }
  }
}))

Thanks in advance!

Your approach will be dictated by how the flow of your app works. If all your data needs is displayed on the same page, then you may want to consolidate multiple queries into one for performance benefits. If you have separate pages (e.g. patients page, services page, orders page) then you'll want to keep your requests seprate. Tell us a bit more about your app so we can help you better!
